# How can I clear a checkbox when a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript

I have single check box for a toggle:

`<label><input type="checkbox" name="myfield" id="myfield" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Sound On</label>`

and users can click it to enable sound on the site. I want to uncheck the checkbox is an href link is clicked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't the page redirect when you click an anchor with an href ?

Comment: Do you mean: `window.onbeforeunload=function() {document.getElementById("myfield").checked=false;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to attach an event listener to the link, which will get notified whenever the link is click. In the event listener, you just need to uncheck the checkbox.

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" name="myfield" id="myfield" />
<label>Sound On</label>
<a id="myhref">uncheck</a>
<script>
    // Get a reference to "myhref".
    var myhref = document.getElementById("myhref");
    // Get a reference to "myfield".
    var myfield = document.getElementById("myfield");
    // Attach an event listener to "myhref", which gets notifier when "myhref" is clicked.
    myhref.addEventListener("click", function() {
        // "myhref" is click. So, uncheck "myfield"
        myfield.checked = false;
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear about what do you want? but this may help you

```
function uncheck()
{
document.getElementById('myfield').checked=false;
}
```

call this function in the onclick of the anchor tag.

be brief about why do you want to do like this? and what you are trying to achieve then we can think and give any other better way.